# Python-Pandas: Reassigning column value based on its existence in a list

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I want to check if the dataframe column(item_type) value exists in a list. If not, I want to reassign the existing column value to another value. Here is the code I am trying.

```
item_cat = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H']
pdata['item_type']  = np.where((pdata['item_type'] not in item_cat) , 'I', pdata['item_type'])
```

I am getting the below error.

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()
```

How do I sort this out ??

Answer (score 1):

```
item_cat = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H']

a = pd.Series(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'Z'])
a.loc[~a.isin(item_cat)] = 'I'
```